# how to update firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am querying a realtime firebase database and I think orderByChild cannot be updated on realtime. I want a situation whereby the status will be updated immediately a supervisor was generated from the db without having to relaunch the app because immediately a supervisor is generated from the app, the status changed to "Filled" and I want the app to stop at that moment. From what I saw on stack overflow, they said that the orderByChild query should be moved inside the snapshot that has the listener and I don't know how to do it.

```
private void getSupervisors() {

    Query databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Supervisors").orderByChild("status").equalTo("Not Filled");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                List<String> supervisorsList =new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                        supervisorsList.add(dataSnapshot.child("sid").getValue().toString());
                    }
                supervisorChose = supervisorsList.get(new Random().nextInt(supervisorsList.size()));
                Log.d("Main","Supervisor List contains "+supervisorsList);
                Log.d("Main","Supervisor chose is "+supervisorChose);

            }else {
                //Toast.makeText(StudentRegistrationActivity.this, "No Supervisor in the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(StudentRegistrationActivity.this, "Error From the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error message?

Comment: the idea was that when a supervisor is being retrieved on random basis as shown in the code, the retrieved supervisor is been assigned to a student and the db is updated. the situation continue till all the supervisors are filled. The issue is that when the supervisor are all filled, the database changes all the supervisors status to "filled" but my app still retrieve the supervisors whose status is "filled" which means that the app is not updated with the supervisor's status at real time. The app supposed to query the supervisors whose status are not filled as indicated in my query.

Comment: Immediately the last available supervisor is assigned to a student, the app supposed to return null instantly which shows that there is no supervisor in the db again whose status is "Not Filled"

Comment: That's the issue I am facing @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That is repeating the use-case you already outlined in your question. What I'm not clear on what exact line in the code you shared isn't working. I.e. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? --- I.e. this *could* be: "When I step through the `onDataChange` line by line, I see that it updates `supervisorsList` with the right users and picks a `supervisorChose ` at random, but it never shows that chosen supervisor in my UI"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: I didn't want it to be shown on the UI, the picked supervisor is used elsewhere. Actually I solved the issue by moving to another activity after successful registration. With that, my getSupervisors was updated from the database when a new user want to register. thanks for all your time